# Basic Auth with RestTemplate

Tags: resttemplate, basic-authentication

I've been trying to pass the basic auth with the restTemplate and it's not even passing the auth header to the server. Here is the bean definition what i'm using `

```
@Bean RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test:test"));

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In general, client does not know what kind of authentication server expects. So the client does not send basic authentication headers before server requests them. See [Server side of basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Server_side).

This is your case, if server requested authentication `RestTemple`, as you set it, would make second request with headers.